# Hot water not working, nothing comes out of the faucet

Tags: faucet, kitchen-sink

There's no water coming out of our kitchen faucet. When you turn on the cold water it works but when you turn the hot water on, nothing comes out. We recently had it installed about 4 months ago. Do you think something's stuck or clogged in the water cartridge?[image]

Comment: sure, something could be blocking the hot line

Comment: If the hot water is running in all of your other faucets it could be a problem between the shutoff valve under the sink and your faucet. If your hot water shutoff under the sink is a multi-turn valve with a washer, the washer may have broken apart and clogged the strainer. If your hot water was running one day and then stopped the next, that's quite unusual but I'mm 99% sure the problem is in the 3 feet nbetween valve and faucet.

Comment: Did it *ever* work?  Were any changes made to the electrical panel(s), even if they are for unrelated circuits?

Answer (score 2):

If it is only this fixture, then I would check the shutoff valve first. It should be under the sink, it has a handle that can be turned on/off.